# Google Analytics event tracking -Contact Form Submit

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to track when a user clicks on the submit form button and they send contact information. I have this code on the contact page:

`<input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn big btn_submit_form" onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contact', eventAction: 'Information Request', eventLabel: 'Contact Form'});">`

I am using Universal Analytics.

In my Google Analytics account, I have the goal description Name as Contact Form Submit, and the Goal Type is Event. The event conditions are as follows:

- Category -Equals to- Contact
- Action -Equals to- Information Request
- Label -Equals to- Contact Form

with the Value field being left empty.

I have "Use the Event value as the Goal value for the conversion" set to  yes.

However, Google Analytics doesn't seem to be tracking the event. Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you see the event in real time reports?

Comment: no, it doesn't even show up in behavior -> events either.

Comment: Can you share your website? I don't see anything wrong with the code. So you are triggering your event, and then immediately checking in Real-Time reports? (RT reports has a window of 30 minutes). It won't show up yet in the Standard Reports for at least 24 hours, during which time the data needs to be processed.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to share the website (as it's not mine), could there be any possible answer to why it's not working?

Comment: Not sure, but you can check other things in your Real-Time reports, like your own visits, just to rule out that Analytics isn't working at all perhaps. Make sure you check the reports immediately after visiting your page though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely problem here is that your page is being unloaded before the event hit has time to send. When you submit a form on a web page, most browsers will stop executing JavaScript and start loading whatever new page the form's `action` attribute is pointing to.

The general workaround for this is to call `preventDefault` on the form's `submit` event, wait for the hit to successfully send to Google Analytics, and then manually re-trigger the form submit.

Here's how that might look (note: I'm using jQuery for simplicity):

```
$('#my-form').on('submit', function(event) {
  // Prevent the browser's default form submission action.
  event.preventDefault();

  ga('send', 'event', {
    eventCategory: 'Contact',
    eventAction: 'Information Request',
    eventLabel: 'Contact Form',
    hitCallback: function() {
      $('my-form').trigger('submit');
    }
  });
});
```

The key part in the above code is the `hitCallback` function, which gets invoked when GA returns success from the event hit beacon.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing the event to the form submit, instead of the button click:

```
<form onSubmit="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contact', eventAction: 'Information Request', eventLabel: 'Contact Form'});">
```

The form can be submitted in ways other than the clicking the submit button (for instance pressing enter in an input field)

Also, in my experience, the tracking will post correctly almost every time, even when you do not call preventDefault on the event.